# How do I get the last prism in Winners?

Tags: edge

There is a prism hiding behind the wall towards the end of Winners, and I have no idea how to get it. The best strategy I could think of was to try and get some edge time on one of the moving panels near the prism and then change to another panel mid-air, but I'm not even sure if you can switch from edge time on one panel to edge time on another panel that quickly.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

This was a surprisingly easy one to get, as I failed to notice one very important step: You can just roll up to the ledge from the top of the last "t".
[image]
From there, it's just a matter of timing your falls and rolls right to make sure you get back around to the goal (which hopefully shouldn't be too hard for anyone who has gotten this far into the game).